# Add new tags to an existing filter on Stack Exchange

Tags: support, tags, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

When I log in to stackexchange.com and go to "Filtered Questions" I can see the questions based on my filter. Now I want to add a new *tag* in the same filter so that I can check and answer questions of that tag as well, but I am not able to see any option regarding the same.

Do I need to delete the filter and create it again with my existing tags and the new ones? If that is the case then isn't it a little cumbersome and that the site should be modified to incorporate this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You click *edit* next to the filter name (or create [a new filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/new) if you don't have existing filters)

[image]

Now add the tag of your choice and click 'Add Rule' (this is easy overlooked due to the orange *Save changes* button)

[image]

After clicking 'Add Rule' you see the new filter being added under 1. Notice that you can uncheck the tags that you want to remove.

[image]

Enter or change your e-mail address and save your changes permanently by clicking 'Save Changes':

[image]

Done! You succesfully edited your filter.