# How do I get email notifications of new questions?

Tags: discussion, email-notification

I would like to get email notifications when someone submits a new questions to a specific community. I have not found a setting for this in my group profile page.

Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to follow a user automatically?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41483/is-it-possible-to-follow-a-user-automatically) I know it does not exactly state e-mails but it seems to me you are essentially wanting to "follow" a use, in a similar style to a social media site, so the answer is no, you can't.

Comment: You can set up  a filter: https://stackexchange.com/filters Here is an answer of mine that shows with images how to leverage some of  the filter features: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224536/add-new-tags-to-an-existing-filter-on-stack-exchange/224557#224557 you see option 3 there, where you can tick the box and provide an email.

Comment: I have set up filters, but I am not getting email notifications for new questions posted to a community. I don't want to follow a user, but keep an eye on all questions coming in.